# List of Diablo 2 Mods that add quests

Tags: mods, diablo-ii

Is there a List of Diablo 2 Mods that add quests.

Comment: While I appreciate your effort to reduce the scope and remove the subjectivity, the better course of action over posting a new question would have been to edit your [previous question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/great-diablo-2-mods-closed), using the "edit" option in the lower left. "Closing" which is what happened, only makes the question incapable of receiving answers. It's still able to be edited and commented on.

Comment: and reopened...

Comment: I hope this becomes a good wiki.  I'd like to see what everyone is using from a D2 mod perspective.  Man do I love that game.

Answer (score 9):

[Median XL](http://modsbylaz.hugelaser.com/) is a popular mod that adds "uberquests" that involve tough new bosses, in addition to a whole bunch of other changes.  It is also one of the few mods that still work with the latest version of the game.

Answer (score 1):

I played Eastern Sun recently and really enjoyed the changes he made. It was both harder than D2 and yet easier in some ways. I won't spoil it but it has a Japanese motif which makes it different and he worked hard to change the areas and make things a little more convenient for players.

Zy-El is an older mod (1.09d is the max patch it works on) but it also has some appeal. I've been playing that recently and while it is uber tough (still in act one at level 32) it has some very interesting ideas and is a bit more loose in terms of it's fantasy setting. (Celebrity Posters? hmmm...) Anyway seems fun so far if a bit frustrating. Not sure how much of it is actually new quest wise but the first areas are bigger than vanilla.

(Both of these are findable at the Phrozen Keep archives: http://phrozenkeep.hugelaser.com/)

Comment: Does Eastern Sun *add* quests? I thought it only tweaks the rewards and reorders a few (eg. Nihlathak), but I haven't played it for a while...